# Teaming/Spanning Switch Ports

Tags: switch

I like to team NICs on my servers. Since most workstations are giga-bit anymore I want to provide my servers a bit more bandwidth. I've read various things that say I am/am not supposed to bond the ports on the switch. I see benefit in doing it as I'm not sure how the switch ARP table handles the same MAC address on multiple ports. Suggestions on the "ideal" way to do it?

If it matters, I have mix (various locations) of Dell and HP, web managed, Layer 2 switches. Servers are mostly Dell with Broadcom NICs.

Comment: NIC Teaming, port bonding (link aggregation) and port spanning are three different things. Which one(s) are you specifically interested in?

Comment: Do you really have a need for more bandwidth to your servers?

Comment: @ewwhite - Agreed. Doing something without supporting evidence/data that it actually needs to be done is never the right thing to do.

Comment: I can't say that I know one giga-bit link is being saturated, I've done it because the capability is there and I want the server to have faster access.

Comment: The Teaming is done at the server level, I believe the switch I was looking at made "port bonding" available in the management console.

Comment: @ewwhite - Are there disadvantages to bonding/teaming? If you have un-used NICs isn't it a logical choice to put them into service?

Comment: More info on the server... what OS are you running?

Comment: 99.9999% of the time you bond NIC's at servers to provide redundancy (as having two different arms). Remember that bonding two 1gbps NIC's will NOT give you 2gbps bandwith, it will give you 2x1gbps..

Comment: @pauska - So, for teaming I should run cables into different switches to gain redundancy. Does that mess with ARP tables on switches? I've assumed (maybe incorrectly) that teaming creates a virtual MAC address. And, I have my teams all set for load balancing (Broadcom). My Server 2008 shows Smart Load Balancing and Failover.

Comment: There are different implementations for load balancing, and it's too much to discuss here on the site. Read the documentation that came with the load-balancing software you're using, it should explain when you should use which one, and how you should configure things in the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the server serving? I rarely bond connections on servers unless I know that bandwidth is a concern *or* I need to connect to multiple (stacked) switches for redundancy.

You probably don't have the need, but you should be able to create [LACP bonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol#Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol) on your switch and configure the server side appropriately... What is the OS of the server?

Comment: Mix of OS's, mostly Server 2003 and Server 2008. Some are SBS boxes, two SQL boxes, one doing LOB Electronic Medical Records, the other hosting Great Plains.

Comment: Ok, so for the servers that are teamed, I want to configure switches accordingly then. Thanks.